# maximum of a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $q$ be an integer $\ge2$, $k$ and $f$ be two positives integers.
I try to find
$$\max\{\sum_{l_1+\cdots+l_f=k}l_iq^{l_i}\mid (l_1,\cdots,l_f)\in(\mathbb N_0)^f\}$$
I think it is $kq^k$, but no way to prove it.
Does anyone have a proof of that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a,b \in \mathbb N_0$ you have

$$aq^a+bq^b \le aq^{a+b} + bq^{a+b}=(a+b)q^{a+b}$$

because all values are non-negative and $f(x)=q^x$ is increasing.

If you apply this repeatedly to your sum, you get that

$$\sum_{l_1+\cdots+l_f=k}l_iq^{l_i} \le (l_1+l_2+\ldots l_f)q^{l_1+l_2+\ldots l_f} = kq^k.$$

It's also easy to see my first inequality can only be an equality if $a=0$ or $b=0$, so you see that the only possible choice for the $l_i$ to reach that maximal value is that one equals $k$ and the other equal $0$.